# How to install a package built with cygport on Cygwin (so I can uninstall it later)?

Tags: cygwin

I have built a package from https://github.com/fd00/yacp using cygport; however I just noticed that `cygport [packagename.cygport] install` command does NOT install in the cygwin filesystem, but in a subdirectory of the source build directory; as such, executables are not in the cygwin path, and you cannot call them by name.

I have seen:

http://cygwin.1069669.n5.nabble.com/Manual-installation-of-cygport-packages-td132812.html

> So for most cases, it works just fine just to unpack the archive into the
>   root file system in order to test it.

https://cygwin-ports-general.narkive.com/RrfmRgr6/how-to-install-a-package-build-with-cygport

> you could install yourself or by descending to the build directory and doing 'make
>   install' or simply run it from the build directory :-)

So, now I have `packagename.tar.xz` and `packaganame.hint` - can't I use these with the Cygwin setup-x86_64.exe program (so that I'd have a marked entry, when I look up the package name in setup)?

If I "install" by just unpacking `packagename.tar.xz` into the Cygwin root filesystem, how do I "uninstall" then?

Does `cygport` change installation paths in respect to `make install` of the package? If not, then I guess `make install` is an option, because then I should have `make uninstall` too ...

Answer (score 2):

`cygport` is the tool to build packages that can be installed with `Cygwin` `setup-$ARCH.exe` installation.

You can create a local setup structure, and use the `calm` package to create
the needed setup.ini file.

```
$ cygcheck -f /usr/bin/mksetupini
calm-20200220-1
```

Create a website directory similar to the cache you have from downloading, make a  `ARCH/release` directory and copy the content of `dist` for the packages you are interested.
I am using a script like this to prepare the directory for setup

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /pub/altervista/

rm x86/setup.ini x86_64/setup.ini

for i in  x86 x86_64
do
  mksetupini --arch ${i} --inifile=${i}/setup.ini --releasearea=. --disable-check=missing-required-package,missing-depended-package
  bzip2 <${i}/setup.ini >${i}/setup.bz2
  xz -6e <${i}/setup.ini >${i}/setup.xz
done
```

In this moment its structure is like this:

```
$ cd http%3a%2f%2fmatzeri.altervista.org%2f
$ find x86_64/ -type f 

x86_64/release/perl-Cairo/perl-Cairo-1.107-1-src.tar.xz
x86_64/release/perl-Cairo/perl-Cairo-1.107-1.hint
x86_64/release/perl-Cairo/perl-Cairo-1.107-1.tar.xz
x86_64/release/perl-Cairo/perl-Cairo-debuginfo/perl-Cairo-debuginfo-1.107-1.hint
x86_64/release/perl-Cairo/perl-Cairo-debuginfo/perl-Cairo-debuginfo-1.107-1.tar.xz
x86_64/release/perl-Glib/perl-Glib-1.3292-1-src.tar.xz
x86_64/release/perl-Glib/perl-Glib-1.3292-1.hint
x86_64/release/perl-Glib/perl-Glib-1.3292-1.tar.xz
x86_64/release/perl-Glib/perl-Glib-debuginfo
x86_64/release/perl-Glib/perl-Glib-debuginfo/perl-Glib-debuginfo-1.3292-1.hint
x86_64/release/perl-Glib/perl-Glib-debuginfo/perl-Glib-debuginfo-1.3292-1.tar.xz
x86_64/setup.bz2
x86_64/setup.ini
x86_64/setup.xz
```

than you can just install from that Website local directory. A `fake` Website works fine.

Comment: Thanks @matzeri - I finally got to the same, was writing my answer when you posted yours!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, found and followed the instructions here: https://cygwin.com/package-server.html

First install `calm` via Cygwin's `setup.exe` (for me, `setup-x86_64.exe`):

```
Install calm 20200220-1
Install python36-setuptools 41.2.0-1 (automatically added)
```

Then, I have:

```
$ which mksetupini
/usr/bin/mksetupini
```

Note, I have already: `/cygdrive/d/Downloads/cygwin_packages/http%3a%2f%2fcygwin.mirror.constant.com%2f/x86_64` where Cygwin stores downloaded packages; that directory has `release` subdir and `setup.ini` file.

So, now I can create a directory for my custom packages:

```
$ mkdir /cygdrive/d/Downloads/cygwin_packages/cygwin-custom
$ mkdir -p /cygdrive/d/Downloads/cygwin_packages/cygwin-custom/x86_64/release
```

Note that in my source build folder, I have a `dist` subfolder, which contains the packaging:

```
$ ls -la [packagename]-[version]-1bl1.x86_64/dist/[packagename]/
total 2557
drwxr-xr-x 1 user None       0 Mar 21 18:26 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 user None       0 Mar 21 18:26 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 user None     373 Mar 21 18:26 [packagename]-[version]-1bl1.hint
-rw-r--r-- 1 user None  177772 Mar 21 18:26 [packagename]-[version]-1bl1.tar.xz
-rw-r--r-- 1 user None 2430900 Mar 21 18:26 [packagename]-[version]-1bl1-src.tar.xz
drwxr-xr-x 1 user None       0 Mar 21 18:26 [packagename]-debuginfo
drwxr-xr-x 1 user None       0 Mar 21 18:26 lib[packagename]0
drwxr-xr-x 1 user None       0 Mar 21 18:26 lib[packagename]-devel
```

I can just copy this to the arch/release child dir of `cygwin-custom`, and then change directory to `cygwin-custom`:

```
$ cp -a [packagename]-[version]-1bl1.x86_64/dist/[packagename] /cygdrive/d/Downloads/cygwin_packages/cygwin-custom/x86_64/release/
$ pushd /cygdrive/d/Downloads/cygwin_packages/cygwin-custom
```

Now, note that if I just call `mksetupini` as in the above webpage, it will fail:

```
$ mksetupini --arch x86_64 --inifile=x86_64/setup.ini --releasearea=.
mksetupini: package '[packagename]' version '[version]-1bl1' requires nonexistent or errored package 'cygwin'
mksetupini: package '[packagename]' version '[version]-1bl1' requires nonexistent or errored package 'libgcc1'
mksetupini: package '[packagename]' version '[version]-1bl1' requires nonexistent or errored package 'libreadline7'
...
```

... and the file `setup.ini` does not get created!

Then I thought I should symlink  as in the above webpage:

```
$ for ARCH in x86_64 noarch ; do
  mkdir -p ${ARCH}/release
  cd ${ARCH}/release
  ln -s /cygdrive/d/Downloads/cygwin_packages/http%3a%2f%2fcygwin.mirror.constant.com%2f/${ARCH}/release/* .
  cd ../..
done
$ mksetupini --arch x86_64 --inifile=x86_64/setup.ini --releasearea=.
mksetupini: no .hint files in ./noarch/release/adwaita-icon-theme but has files: adwaita-icon-theme-3.26.1-1.tar.xz
mksetupini: no .hint files in ./noarch/release/base-cygwin but has files: base-cygwin-3.8-1.tar.xz
mksetupini: no .hint files in ./noarch/release/base-files but has files: base-files-4.3-2.tar.xz
...
mksetupini: package '[packagename]' version '[version]-1bl1' requires nonexistent or errored package 'cygwin'
mksetupini: package '[packagename]' version '[version]-1bl1' requires nonexistent or errored package 'libgcc1'
mksetupini: package '[packagename]' version '[version]-1bl1' requires nonexistent or errored package 'libreadline7'
mksetupini: package '[packagename]' version '[version]-1bl1' depends nonexistent or errored package 'cygwin'
...
```

... and this does not create `setup.ini` either.

Finally I found https://github.com/cascent/neovim-cygwin/issues/7 that mentioned the switch `--okmissing required-package` - so, finally this command:

```
$ mksetupini --arch x86_64 --inifile=x86_64/setup.ini --releasearea=. --okmissing required-package
```

... will finally create `setup.ini` - which will only contain our custom built packages, as they are the only ones that have a `.hint` file ( I don't have any `.hint` files in the `http%3a%2f%2fcygwin.mirror.constant.com%2f` directory, where cygwin usually downloads packages ):

```
$ cat x86_64/setup.ini
# This file was automatically generated at 2020-03-21 19:42:00 CET.
#
# If you edit it, your edits will be discarded next time the file is
# generated.
#
# See https://sourceware.org/cygwin-apps/setup.ini.html for a description
# of the format.
release: cygwin
arch: x86_64
setup-timestamp: 1584816120

@ [packagename]
sdesc: "Blah blah ..."
...
```

Now, start Cygwin `setup.exe`, and when the choice screen is: "Cygwin Setup - Choose Installation Type"; here switch from "Install from Internet (...)" to "Install from Local Directory"; on Next > keep Root directory the same; on Next > Select Local Package Directory: I chose `D:\Downloads\cygwin_packages\cygwin-custom` - on Next > : Select Packages: View Full, then [packagename] is listed there ... and can be installed - and dependencies are resolved, too:

```
Install [packagename] [version]-1bl1
Install lib[packagename]0 [version]-1bl1 (automatically added)
```

And finally, after installation, I can call `[packagename].exe` by name directly in the Cygwin bash shell!

Not too bad of a process, but can get a bit involved if you cannot find the right documentation ...